# Using '-c' when calling vim from terminal

Tags: terminal, load, sessions

My issue is with using the -c while calling vim from terminal like

```
$ vim -c jk
```

**I want to be able to open the last session before quitting on typing `viml` in terminal**

For this I made a map to save the session as 'zzz' on exiting vim. All that works perfectly.

Now I made an alias in my `.zshrc`/`.bashrc`:

```
# SLoad is from a plugin Startify, it loads the session  
alias viml='vim -c :SLoad zzz'
```

But the issue I am facing is that when I run `viml` alias, this happens

[image]

Its really annoying that I have to press enter to start working. I tried using `<cr>` at end but it doesn't work.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you need to escape your `space`:

```
alias viml='vim -c :SLoad\ zzz'
```

Let's consider a simpler case:

I have a file named `a.vim` in the current directory and my alias is:

```
alias vv="vim -c :sp a.vim"
```

When I run `vv` I get two buffers with `a.vim` on each.

Why is that?

Vim open `a.vim` and **then** execute the command `:sp`, which split the buffer in two, opening `a.vim` again. The alias is used as follow:

```
 vim -c :sp a.vim
```

Which means `vim a.vim` and then `:sp`. `:sp` and `a.vim` are two different arguments.

Now I have the alias:

```
alias vv="vim -c :sp\ a.vim"
```

Vim open, and execute `:sp a.vim`, opening the `a.vim` file in a new split.

This is because the `space` is escaped and thus the `:sp a.vim` is one argument.